# use jdbc to connect sybase ASE

Tags: jdbc, sybase

I want to use jdbc to connect Sybase ASE, but, I got an error in the following:

```
JZ006: 捕获到 IO 例外:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused: connect" is a low level socket error meaning that nothing is listening on the port you are trying to connect to (or it was blocked by a firewall).

This means that either you have no Sybase ASE running, it is not listening on the IP address you are connecting to, it is listening on a different port, or a firewall blocks your connection.